# Where to store complex data in the navigation-based application

Tags: java, android, navigation, components, viewmodel

I have an app that has a lot of data that I need between the pages, such as:
design settings, user parameters, scanner access, printer queue, multiple things that got calculated and formed on one page and will be used on the others.

The general idea of the app is: you quickly select options or input data on each page and then it forms an order, sends it and prints it.

I have several repositories for different things but I can't get how to give access to them from the destination-fragments.

I'm pretty new to Android so I'm trying to find the best way to build this system but failing to do so.
What I found so far:

- **Room** - I don't think so. I honestly tried it for several weeks but loading and saving data is unbearably slow especially when it's just a bunch of menu-pages flipping one after another. Also, I don't need to save data locally between the sessions, so it kind of misses the point of the local database.
- **Send some simple strings/numbers between the fragments** - serialization/deserialization of everything I need for each menu doesn't sound great.
- **ViewModel factory** - this way you need to create and store the ViewFactory somewhere and then access it from each fragment and then build a new ViewModel with it. Kind of might work but looks weird. How should it work? We have a link to the Factory in the "main" ViewModel and then get a link to this "main" app's VM, read the factory and then init local fragment's VM?
- **One big application's ViewModel** - doesn't sound right: too big, too bulky.
- **Singleton(s)** - that's just sad.
- **Dependency injection** - I didn't try **Dagger** yet (going to, right now). Is it the thing I'm looking for?

I tried to google a lot on this topic but all of the answers look like: "here's how to pass a simple string between the screens", how do people organize the more complex applications? Maybe there's a more sophisticated way to split the application state into some kind of services or other terms that I'm missing.

Could you please help me to understand the proper application architecture in terms of state and data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your solution is something between a session implementation (in memory or using Room) and a `ViewModel` for the parts where a screen depends on another. If it is a flow I recommend you to use a way to share the `ViewModel` between the fragments like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) or [this](https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-android/viewmodel?id=shared-viewmodel) (which I use and recommend) and then setting it as a state for the rest of the flow, leading to shared data that survives some config changes. If you need the settings surviving throughout the app execution you should implement a session using a simple class singleton or a Room implementation.